# Run gnu global in emacs mini buffer

Tags: emacs, global

I know there is ggtags for emacs, but I want to execute "global" directly from mini buffer, and I expect if there are search result, I can use "next-error" to navigate them. Simply speaking, I want to use global just like "grep" from mini-buffer. Is there a way for it?  Thanks

Comment: Doing `M-x grep` and replacing it with the `global` invocation perhaps? Although `next-error` has to be able to parse the output, which might or might not work with `global` output. But you should read the doc string of `next-error`: `C-h f next-error`.

Comment: yes, type M-x grep and then replace grep with global, it can run, but can't use next-error to navigator the result. It is the problem